# getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, json

I'm making a web program that displays the data from 2 tables in the same mysql database. For this I have a php file that outputs 2 json objects (named hist and hist2). I'm trying to display the locations in the tables as markers in a Google Maps map. I'm getting an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` in the line I'll show you.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {     


var lat = "48.85809";
var lon = "2.294694";
var myPath = [];
var myPath2 = [];
infoWindows = Array();
infoWindows2 = Array();
markers = Array();
markers2 = Array();
var image = 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/isometric-city-basic-transport/48/truck-front-01-48.png';
var image2 = 'https://i.imgur.com/FGEuaWh.png';
function initMap() {

         var myOptions = {
             zoom: 16,
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lon)),
             panControl: true,
             zoomControl: true,
             scaleControl: true,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    }
    function addMarker(latLng,time,id, map) {
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: latLng,
                   map: map,
                   icon: image,
                   infoWindowIndex: id
               });
   var content = '<div id="Marker_Time">' +
  '<h6>' + 'Información' + '</h6>' +
  '<p>' + time + '</p>' + '</div>'; 
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: content
              });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',
      function(event) {
              infoWindow.open(map, marker);

            }
      ); 
          infoWindows.push(infoWindow);
          markers.push(marker);
          return marker;
             }
      function addMarker2(latLng,time,id,rpm, map) {
               var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: latLng,
                   map: map,
                   icon: image,
                   infoWindowIndex: id
               });
  var content2 = '<div id="Marker_Time">' +
  '<h6>' + 'Información' + '</h6>' +
  '<p>' + time2 + '</p>' +'<p>' + rpm +'</p>' + '</div>' ;
var infoWindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: content2
});
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',
            function(event) {
              infoWindow.open(map, marker);

            }
);   
    infoWindows2.push(infoWindow2)
markers2.push(marker2);
               return marker2;              
             }


  <?php 
   ob_start();
   include_once 'finalquery2.php'; 
  $output = ob_end_clean(); ?>
        var json_hist = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(hist));
        INIT_LAT = parseFloat(json_hist[json_hist.length - 1].Latitude);
        INIT_LON = parseFloat(json_hist[json_hist.length - 1].Longitude);
        $(json_hist).each(function() {
          var ID = this.ID;
          var LATITUDE = this.Latitude;
          var LONGITUDE = this.Longitude;
          var TIME=this.DateTime;
          myCoord2 = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(LATITUDE), parseFloat(LONGITUDE));
          myPath.push(myCoord2);
          var myPathTotal2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: myPath,
            strokeColor: '#e95d3c',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 5
          });
          myPathTotal2.setPath(myPath)
          myPathTotal2.setMap(map);
          addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE),TIME,ID, map);
            });

         var json_hist2 = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(hist2));
        INIT_LAT2 = parseFloat(json_hist2[json_hist2.length - 1].Latitude);
        INIT_LON2 = parseFloat(json_hist2[json_hist2.length - 1].Longitude);
        $(json_hist2).each(function() {
          var ID2 = this.ID;
          var LATITUDE2 = this.Latitude;
          var LONGITUDE2 = this.Longitude;
          var TIME2 =this.DateTime;
          var rpm = this.RPM;
          myCoord2b = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(LATITUDE2), parseFloat(LONGITUDE2));
          myPath2.push(myCoord2b);
          var myPathTotal2b = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: myPath,
            strokeColor: '#000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 5
          });
          myPathTotal2b.setPath(myPath)
          myPathTotal2b.setMap(map);
          addMarker2(new google.maps.LatLng(LATITUDE2, LONGITUDE2),TIME2,ID2,rpm, map);
        });         //Here is the Uncaught SyntaxError

      </script>
```

I paste it in Sublime and everything appears to be in order, so I don't know why I'm getting this problem, which also prevents the map from loading at all. That `});` closes the `$(json_hist2).each(function() {` line.

Comment: Properly indenting your code goes a long way on preventing syntax errors. It is not there only for the looks and satisfying my OCD.

Comment: I know I know, but I'm editing someone else's code and so I'm working with that I got ¯_(ツ)_/¯ my apologies. Is it part of the problem here, or is it just that it makes it harder to read?

Comment: It says there is an uncaught syntax error because it is expecting a closing } thats why unexpected end of input, it was expecting more

Comment: To find such syntax error you have to use correct indentation, to see where the problem might be. So yes it is part of the problem here. If you use correct indentation you will see that braces are missing at the end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a } after the return marker2; } I believe you aren't closing out the original ready function.

Comment: Now I'm getting other errors, but they're unrelated. I think that was it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The code itself indicates that `return marker2; }` is not the place where the `}` has to be added, and the code is missing a `})` and not  just a `}`.